# Add List<T> to beginning of another List<T>

Tags: c#, string, list, insert

I'm looking for a way to add a List to the beginning of another List (specifically, strings).

I have found the List.Insert method, but that is for a single object.

I have thought about a for each loop to insert the item, but that would add them backwards.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that inserting items at the start of a list is inefficient (particularly when performed in a loop), because every subsequent item has to be moved into the next slot in the backing array. Using InsertRange generally only does a single copy for the entire operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`List.InsertRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/884ee1fz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
list.InsertRange(0, otherStrings);
```

Comment: Aha! How did I miss that?
Thanks!

Comment: this is much better.I didn't even know there is an InsertRange method since I'm always using Concat :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new list entirely you need to do;

```
 List<Type> combinedLists = new List<Type>();
 combinedLists.AddRange(list1);
 combinedLists.AddRange(list2);
```

If you want them in the opposite order then reverse the `AddRange` calls. You can also append to the end of either of the lists with `AddRange` or use `InsertRange` to add the list in a specific location.